# Nested for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

I have a decent beginner understanding of regular for loops but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around nested for loops in Java.

In the problem I'm working on, I have a constant integer that is a max number, and then I ask the user for 4 different number inputs. From those 4 inputs, I'm trying to determine which of them I can fit 'inside' the constant integer I declared.

IE: If the constant integer is 30 and the user inputs 5, 9, 3, and 21 it will tell them they can only use the 5, 9, and 3 because the 21 would be too large to add.

The problem in story form is, a user has a knapsack that holds a certain amount of weight. The program asks the user to input 4 different item weights and then decides which items it can fit in the bag.

This is for a school project so I'm required to use nested for loops.

Comment: do you really need a loop for it? is it not a simple addition ?

Comment: Couldn't they also add 5, 3 and 21 (=29) or 9 and 21 (=30)?

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain a bit about what you don't understand or what aspect you are having a difficult time with we could more directly answer your question.

Comment: Are the user inputs handled in order?  Like you start with 5, add 9 to get 14, 3 to get 17 and then find that you can't add 21 after that?  If so, I don't understand what you need nested for-loops for...

Comment: No, the numbers aren't static except for the constant integer I mentioned. The problem is basically a person has a knapsack that can hold so much weight/items. The user inputs the weight of 4 different items and then the program decides which of the 4 items it can take. Multiple items can be taken if the weight allows.

Comment: Are the inputs always sorted least to greatest? Judging from your question prompt, I would think the final goal is to get the closest to weight capacity. You say 21 is too large to add, but it isn't. I could fit 21, 3, and 5 and now my bag is at 29/30 capacity, verses 3, 5, 9 which only gets me to 17. If this is the goal, then you are dealing with a slightly more complex problem which will require recursion to solve. Is that the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Any easy way to think of nested for loops is to ignore the fact that they are nested. 
By convention, you will typically use `i` for the outer loop's increment counter and `j` for the inner loop's, which is the most important thing to keep straight in the beginning. If that is a point of confusion for you, it would likely benefit you to use more descriptive names for your increment variables than the letters 'i' and 'j', for example `outer` and `inner`.

At any given time when you are trying to structure your program's logic you only need to focus on the `for` loop that you are working most directly inside - at least when you are starting out and learning about them for the first time.

Comment: In fact when first starting you might consider using more descriptive names.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea. Nested loops scale terribly, and you need to make sure first if they are what you really need in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any JAVA but I know that C# is pretty much the same.

I would do like this:

```
int max = 30;
int value = 0;
int counter = 0;
int[] input[4] = new int[5, 9, 3, 21];
bool[] canAddInput[4] = new bool[false, false, false, false];

for(value; value <= max; )
{
    for(counter; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
         value += input[i];
         if(value<=max)
             canAddInput[i] = true;
    }

    if(counter >= 4)
        Break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the code to the inverse boolean impressions. Othervise there would be a possibility of wrong value.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without arrays but instead receiving the values for variables via user input (dialog box)? Right now I just have integers declared and then assign values via user input but I'm not sure how to put them to use correctly.

Comment: Yes ofcurse their is, but I am not sure how to recieve those in JAVA. In C# WPF you would use `input[x] = int.Parse(TextBlock.text)` and in C++ you would use `cin >> input[x]`

Answer (score 0):

To understand nested loops, you can start with simple examples, and then try harder one. For example, let's suppose you want to make a counter.

```
int i, j;
for (i=0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(i+""+j)
    }
}
```

The output is numbers from 00 to 99. You can write the output of the loop in a paper or something to see how it works.
Let's take the example of this loop, you have this output:

```
00 //here your program entered the outer loop, i has now the value 0, after that, you enter to the inner loop, i remains 0, but j will change in the next iteration
01 // you are still in the first iteration of the outer loop, but the inner loop is on the second
02 // and so on ....
03
04
05
06
07
08
09 // ... until the inner loop finished looping
10 // once the inner loop finished looping, the outer loop changes again, and we are back to the inner loop
```

Once all that is clear on your mind, you can decide how your nested loop will be like. What variables need to be used in the outer loop, and what variables for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```java
package com.examplehub.basics;

public class ForNestedLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * ####
         * ####
         * ####
         */
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        /*
         * Outer loop iteration 1
         * i = 1; j = 1
         * i = 1; j = 2
         * i = 1; j = 3
         * i = 1; j = 4
         * Outer loop iteration 2
         * i = 2; j = 1
         * i = 2; j = 2
         * i = 2; j = 3
         * i = 2; j = 4
         * Outer loop iteration 3
         * i = 3; j = 1
         * i = 3; j = 2
         * i = 3; j = 3
         * i = 3; j = 4
         */
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {

            System.out.println("Outer loop iteration " + i);

            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; ++j) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i + "; j = " + j);
            }
        }

        /*
         * 1
         * 12
         * 123
         * 1234
         * 12345
         */
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("" + j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        /*
         * 1*1=1
         * 1*2=2    2*2=4
         * 1*3=3    2*3=6   3*3=9
         * 1*4=4    2*4=8   3*4=12  4*4=16
         * 1*5=5    2*5=10  3*5=15  4*5=20  5*5=25
         * 1*6=6    2*6=12  3*6=18  4*6=24  5*6=30  6*6=36
         * 1*7=7    2*7=14  3*7=21  4*7=28  5*7=35  6*7=42  7*7=49
         * 1*8=8    2*8=16  3*8=24  4*8=32  5*8=40  6*8=48  7*8=56  8*8=64
         * 1*9=9    2*9=18  3*9=27  4*9=36  5*9=45  6*9=54  7*9=63  8*9=72  9*9=81
         */
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + "*" + i + "=" + j * i + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        /*
         * A
         * AB
         * ABC
         * ABCD
         * ABCDE
         */
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            char letter = 'A';
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(letter++);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        /*
         * 1 2 3
         * 4 5 6
         * 7 8 9
         */
        int[][] array = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        /*
         * 1 2 3
         * 4 5 6
         * 7 8 9
         */
        for (int[] ints : array) {
            for (int anInt : ints) {
                System.out.print(anInt + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/examplehub/Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/examplehub/basics/ForNestedLoop.java)