# Trouble using a char Array to see if a certain char is in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to count the amount of vowels in a string using a char array, but whenever I compare the two I get a message. In my for loop, I either get it to count a small string like 'hello', an error where it wont count at all, or it reaches an out of bounds exception. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
public class App 
{
    
    public static int vowelCounter(String myString)
    {
        if(myString.length() > 0)
        {
            char vowelArray[] = {'A','E','I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
            int countedVowels = 0; 
            for(int i = 0; myString.length() > 0; i++)
            {
         
//The if statement below seems to work until the string gets too big. You then get an Out of Bounds exception error. 
//eIf i don't put the 'i' in the index for vowelArray, the count will not increase.

                if(myString.contains(myString.valueOf(vowelArray[i])))
                {
                    countedVowels++; 
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;     
                }
            }
            return countedVowels;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the string is being passed in from another method.

Comment: Add details by editing the Question, not adding Comments.

Comment: Don't really use this too much. I wasn't sure what was easier for the reader to see/understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `i` as the variable name, use something more meaningful. Your bug should then jump out at you.

```
for( int indexIntoMyString = 0; myString.length() > 0; indexIntoMyString ++ )
    …
    if( myString.contains( myString.valueOf( vowelArray[ indexIntoMyString ] ) ) )
```

Hint:

- You are not looping your array of vowels.
- Learn about [nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912419/642706).

---

By the way, the `char` type is legacy, essentially broken since Java 2. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

To work with individual characters, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of the for loop 'myString.length() > 0' is always 'true' because you don't minimize myString neither the length of it. This is why you i increases without limit and your index i will get out of bounds of the vowelArray.

What you should do use two loops one for the traverse of the string and another for the vowelArray. Somthing like this:

```
    public class App {
    public static final char[] VOWELS = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    public static int vowelCounter(String myString) {
        if (!myString.isEmpty()) {
            int countedVowels = 0;
            myString = myString.toLowerCase();
            char[] word = myString.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                char currentChar = word[i];
                for (char c : VOWELS) {
                    if (currentChar == c){
                        countedVowels++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return countedVowels;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

or use an set instead like this

```
    public class App {
    public static final Set<Character> VOWELS = Set.of('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    public static int vowelCounter(String myString) {
        if (!myString.isEmpty()) {
            int countedVowels = 0;
            myString = myString.toLowerCase();
            char[] word = myString.toCharArray();

            for (char c : word) {
                if (VOWELS.contains(c)) {
                    countedVowels++;
                }
            }
            return countedVowels;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```